# Getting PermissionError when the contents of 2 zip files with the same name are different

Tags: python, zip

I download the zip file from the email and extract the contents with the code below.

If there are 2 zip files with the same name, they both download, but the files inside the two zip files must be the same. If the contents of 2 files with the same name are different, I get an error and cannot download.

Error:

`PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`

Code:

```
import zipfile
import os
import shutil


path_to_zip_file = file_path

myZip = zipfile.ZipFile(path_to_zip_file)

for file in myZip.filelist:
    if file.filename.endswith(".txt"):
        if os.path.basename(file.filename) in os.listdir(intermediary_path):
            source = myZip.open(file)
            target = open(os.path.join(intermediary_path, os.path.basename(file.filename).split(".")[0] + "_" + str(counts) + "." + os.path.basename(file.filename).split(".")[1]), "wb")
            counts = counts + 1
        else:
            source = myZip.open(file)
            target = open(os.path.join(intermediary_path, os.path.basename(file.filename)), "wb")

            with source, target:
                shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)
```